# Symfony PostGIS - db reverse engineering

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, postgis, reverse-engineering

situation:
Symfony 3.2
jsor/doctrine-postgis 1.3 - configured with service and required data type in config

PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension.
Two schemas:

- geo
- sch1

Schema geo has tabels with geometry.
Schema geo has postgis extension.
Schema geo has views geometry_columns and etc

when I try to run

> ./bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force GeoBundle xml

I get errors

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException]
>     An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT coord_dimension, srid, type
>                     FROM geometry_columns
>                     WHERE f_table_name = ?
>                     AND f_geometry_column = ?' with params ["boisko", "geom"]:
>     SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
>     LINE 2:                 FROM geometry_columns

&

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
>     LINE 2:                 FROM geometry_columns

&

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
>     LINE 2:                 FROM geometry_columns

I wonder if anybody had similar problem and could help me out to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

problem was **search_path** 
as soon I set it up everything works as expected

Comment: IBAW but as it happens I also am trying a reverse engineer from a database with the postgis extension from symfony2.8.24 using `jsor` too and your question is undoubtedly heaven-sent. could you please please tell me how you configured the library to *connect* properly with Symfony? I have never been good at configuring third party tools, I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis#installation) but I'm missing something, should I create a bundle for it, should I copy it somewhere in my project folder structure, where? I will create aquestion if I must please answer

Comment: [check this gist, I hope it will help you out](https://gist.github.com/mysiar/2a309f0191a5f4854d35d5b9beed62b4)

Comment: hi, I really appreciate you answering and just checked your link but, what I saw there was a configuration snippet to be included in config.yml and an example of how to use it in an entity. The problem is IDK where to start, for example, I don't see the path `'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeographyType'` anywhere in my zip so I don't know where to copy the files I have from the zip in the link I gave you(doctrine-postgis-master).I know it's asking a lot but could you walk me through it or point me somewhere on how 2 include this library in symfony2.8 from the beginning. I'll provide link of Q.

Comment: [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/269236/112781) and [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48444757/4770813)

Comment: I do not know what do you mean by zip.
I use composer

Comment: I totally understand but I can not use composer online, so... I got it working, though, thanx for your help!