# config jsor library to make symfony 2/doctrine 2 work with postgis extension

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, postgis

Working with Symfony 2.8.24 and PostGIS

I need to `THE TITLE`. I found [this](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis) in github but the problem is the configuration steps there didn't help me a lot. I don't know if it is because I can't use composer online (proxy) to install it as the first step states.

IRDK where to start, for example, I don't see the path `'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeographyType'` anywhere in [the files I am using](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis/archive/master.zip) so I don't know where to copy them to use them, or maybe it has nothing to do with it.

I know it's asking a lot but could anyone walk me through it or point me somewhere on how 2 include this library in symfony2.8 from the beginning, I have been using Symfony for a while now (not postgis) and still have a really hard time including this kind of third party libs, so we're talking baby steps here. thanx

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have the postgis extension installed on your postgresql server.

Install the package via composer.

```
composer require jsor/doctrine-postgis
```

Add the types to doctrine-bundle's configuration.

Example:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
  orm:
    # [..]
    entity_managers:
      default:
        dql:
          string_functions:
            Geometry:             Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\Geometry
            Geography:            Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\Geography
            ST_Distance:          Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_Distance
            ST_Distance_Sphere:   Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_Distance_Sphere
            ST_DWithin:           Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_DWithin
            ST_GeomFromText:      Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_GeomFromText
            ST_GeographyFromText: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_GeographyFromText
            ST_Transform:         Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_Transform
            ST_Point:             Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_Point
            ST_SetSRID:           Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_SetSRID
            ST_AsEWKT:            Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Functions\ST_AsEWKT
```

Create an entity:

```
namespace My\Entity;

class GeoLocation
{
    protected $latitude;

    protected $longitude;

    protected $point;

    public function __construct($latitude, $longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        $this->setPoint();
    }

    protected function setPoint()
    {
        $this->point = sprintf(
          'POINT(%f %f)', 
          (string)$this->longitude,
          (string)$this->latitude
        );
    }

    public function getPoint()
    {
        return $this->point;
    }

    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return (float) $this->latitude;
    }

    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return (float) $this->longitude;
    }
}
```

Add a mapping for your entity:

```
My\Entity\GeoLocation:
  type: 'entity'
  indexes:
    idx_point:
      columns:
        - 'point'
      flags:
        - 'spatial'
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    longitude:
      nullable: true
      type: 'decimal'
      precision: 9
      scale: 6
    latitude:
      nullable: true
      type: 'decimal'
      precision: 8
      scale: 6
    point:
      nullable: true
      type: 'geography'
      options:
        geometry_type: 'POINT'
        srid: 4326
```

Update your database schema:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update [--force]
```

Now save some points ...

Finally use the postgis types in your doctrine repository:

```
public function findByDistanceFrom($latitude, $longitude, $distanceInMeters)
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('geolocation');
  $pointFrom = 'Geography(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(geolocation.longitude, geolocation.latitude), 4326))';
  $pointTo = 'Geography(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(:longitude, :latitude), 4326))';
  $qb
    ->where( $qb->expr()->eq("ST_DWithin($pointFrom, $pointTo, :distance_in_meters)", $qb->expr()->literal(true) ) )
    ->setParameter('latitude', $latitude)
    ->setParameter('longitude', $longitude)
    ->setParameter('distance_in_meters', $distanceInMeters)
  ;

  return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

Comment: this is a very comprehensive answer but, you might have missed the very important part where I CAN NOT use composer online, which I think prevents me from `composer require jsor/doctrine-postgis`, but I am sure this will help me in the future when I solve my current predicament

Comment: I just had it to work. I think so cause I'm not getting the error I was earlier when trying to ([according to this](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)) `doctrine:mapping:import --filter=tname XBundle yml`: `Unknown database type geometry requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL92Platform may not support it.` which was what prompted me to install `jsor` at first.But then when I try the second step `doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src` I get `[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException] Invalid mapping file FILE.orm.yml' for class <classname>`

Comment: u wouldn't happen to know anything about that, would you? nevertheless 1up 4 ur answer

Comment: never mind again, I can't believe what was happening. Symfony somehow thought it would be ok to name the generated file with a `.` in the name as in `SCHEMA.TABLE.orm.yml`. ASA I changed it and in the namespace in the `yml` file, voilà! Again, thanx for such an elaborate answer, this will help me a great deal in the future